# Android studio, AppCompatActivity import android.support.v7. library not recognize

Tags: android

Libraries from android.support is not recognized

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

compiler

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
```

config

```
 applicationId "com.example.leoandroid.leoandroid"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

tried everything. updating and moreover. its getting on my nerves.

Comment: Use: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

Comment: Check your current using theme is AppCompat (parent) or not.

Comment: same compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'  used compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0' still the same result

Comment: First clean and build  your project  then check possibly issue will be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For API 23:**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

**Or**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
```

Finally

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" // or 23.0.1

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "//"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'



}
```

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Restart Your Project**

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Android Studio! For a same error with higher version, it worked for me.